# rtp decoding issue on p frames

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtsp, rtp

I am streaming an rtsp stream from an IP camera. I have a parser which packages the data into frames based on the rtp payload type. The parser is able to process I frames since these contain the start of frame and end of frame packets, as well as packets in between (this is FU-A payload type).

These are combined to create a complete frame. The problem comes in when I try to construct P frames, from the wireshark dump some of these appear to be fragmented (FU-A payload type) these contain the start of frame and end of frame packets, however these do not contain packets in between. Also in some instances the camera sends strange marked packets with a payload type 1, this according to my understanding should be a complete frame.

Upon processing these two versions of P frames I then use ffmpeg to attempt to decode the frames, I receive errors messages like top block unavailable for intra mode 4x4.

At first I thought this could be due to an old ffmpeg version but I searched the web and recompiled ffmpeg with the same problem.

The I frames appear fragmented and contain lots of packets, some P frame have a start of frame (0x81) and EOF (0x41) but no packets in between and some just looked corrupt starting with 0x41 (seems like this should be the second byte) which gives payload type of 1. I am a novice when it comes to these issues but I looked at rtp documentation and I cannot find an issue with how I handle the data.

Also I stream from VLC and this seems fine but appears to halve the frame rate, I am not sure how they are able to reconstruct frames.

Please could someone help.

Comment: What do you mean by payload type 1? I'm guessing you are confusing the RTP payload type, with the H.264 NAL unit type? Why do you consider these packets strange?

Answer (score 1):

It is common for I-frames to be fragmented since they are usually a lot bigger than p-frames. P-frames can however also be fragmented. However there is nothing wrong with a P-frame that has been fragmented into 2 RTP packets i.e. one with the FU-header start bit set, and the following one with the end bit set. There do not need to be packets in between. For example, if the MTU is 1500, and the NAL unit is 1600 bytes large, this will be fragmented into 2 RTP packets.

As for the packets "looking corrupt" starting with 0x41 without a prior packet with a 0x81, you should examine the sequence number in the RTP header as this will tell you straight away if packets are missing. If you are seeing packet loss, the first thing to try is to increase your socket receiver buffer size.

Since VLC is able to play the stream, there is most likely an issue in the way you are reassembling the NAL units.

Also, in your question it is not always clear which byte you are referring to: I'm assuming that the 0x41 and 0x81 appear in the 2nd byte of the RTP payload, i.e. the FU header in the case where the NAL unit type of the first byte is FU-A.

Finally, note that "payload type" is the RTP payload type (RFC3550), not the NAL unit type defined in the H.264 standard.

Comment: The 0x81 and 0x41 are the second byte of the RTP stream. So some frames start with the sequence 0x3c 0x81..... and end with the sequence 0x3c 0x41.....

Comment: and then I get some that look like 0x41 0xE0....., so as stated I reassemble both types of P frames but both seem to give the error. I actually did try to increase the receive buffer size with little success.